# Index of the four highest values in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find the index of the four highest values in a list.

My code so far finds the highest:

```
for i, j in enumerate(Si['S1']):
        if j == max(Si['S1']):
            numberofhighest=i
```

but i have no idea how to find the four highest without sorting or deleting a value in my list. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: You could do a *partial* sort. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555820/how-can-i-partially-sort-a-python-list

Comment: Also, by the way, your current solution is already more expensive than a full sort (the number of operations grows as the square of the number of elements, and good sorting algorithms can do better than that).

Comment: @jonrsharpe aren't you a little harsh here? OP has at least started and can find the index of the highest value.

Comment: @timgeb well *is* this either of the things I said it isn't?

Comment: @jonrsharpe of course not, I did not mean to imply it was - but maybe OP thought his code just needs some minor tweaks to find the n largest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to use the standard library, a combination of `heapq.nlargest` and `enumerate` should work fine.

Setup:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>> a = [6, 2, 8, 9, 0, 4, 3, 7, 1, 5] # example
```

Getting the four largest elements and their index:

```
>>> nlargest(4, enumerate(a), itemgetter(1))
[(3, 9), (2, 8), (7, 7), (0, 6)]
```

This will give you `(index, value)` tuples for the four largest values. To extract the indices, you can use a list comprehension or another call to `map`.

```
>>> [index for index, value in nlargest(4, enumerate(a), itemgetter(1))]
[3, 2, 7, 0]
>>> map(itemgetter(0), nlargest(4, enumerate(a), itemgetter(1)))
[3, 2, 7, 0]
```

In Python3, you need to construct a list from the return value of map manually, i.e. `list(map(...))`.