# Partially argsort a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, heap, heapsort

I have a KNN, and I need to partially **argsort** a list.

Here is how it works right now in code:

```
sorted_distance_indices = distances.argsort(axis=1)[:,:self.parameters['k']+1]

kplus_1_nearest_classes = self.trainingY[sorted_distance_indices]

...etc.
```

I found this answer, [How can I partially sort a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555820/how-can-i-partially-sort-a-python-list) But I don't see how to adapt the 'heapification' for the argsort task, (and I have no idea how to do language interop in Python, so I don't see how to do the heapsort alg manually)...

Comment: [The native Python implementation of a priority heap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) might help.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got the answer.

Running:

```
sorted_distance_indices = np.argpartition(distances,self.parameters['k']+1,axis=1)[:,:self.parameters['k']+1]
```

Gets the job done.  Open for a faster way.

Comment: I know this is old, but `np.argpartition` only puts the `k`th element in the correct position. Everything before that is not guaranteed to be sorted but will have a smaller distance than the `k`th element