# Python sort and slice a list and save as a new list

Tags: python, sorting, slice

I am learning Python and need help in sort and slice a list. Here is a list of scores in an exam. A new list should be created with top 3 scores in reverse order. Presently I couldn't find a way to sort the list and then slice it in a single statement. Can someone help how this could be written better?

```
all_scores = [97, 98, 62, 100, 72, 51,99]
top3_scores = sorted(all_scores[:],reverse=True)
top3_scores = top3_scores[:3]
OUTPUT: [100, 99, 98]
```

Thanks much for the help!

Comment: `sorted(all_scores, reverse=True)[:3]`. Sorted already makes a copy, you don't need the `[:]`

Comment: Related question: [How can I partially sort a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555820/how-can-i-partially-sort-a-python-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner:

```
top3_scores = sorted(all_scores, reverse=True)[:3]
```

Comment: Alternatively `top3_scores = sorted(all_scores)[:3:-1]`